# Error in Flurry Android analytics

Tags: java, android, google-analytics, flurry, flurry-analytics

I am trying to integrate flurry android integration tool to my app. I have integrated the jar library but I'm stuck at this point as I'm getting some error. Error says
**Cannot resolve method 'onCreate()'**
and **Cannot resolve symbol 'XY**********P2P'**

```
 import com.flurry.android.FlurryAgent;
    import com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;


    public class MainActivity extends Activity {


        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            // init Flurry
            FlurryAgent.init(this, XYB***********2P);
            //....
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Comment: Why is there one more `onCreate` in Activity?

Comment: I'm new in java and android I'don't know if I can use two onCreate methods or not. If not then how would I implement this ? Can you guige me with the code?

Comment: You should not. Just move your code in onCreate to the second onCreate

Comment: Itried it like this   
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        super.onCreate();
        // init Flurry
        FlurryAgent.init(this, XYB7G3B*********2P);
        //....

Comment: And the problem is??

Comment: Same error with this code as well

Comment: Change to `private final static String FLURRY_KEY = "XYB***********2P";
        @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Flurry FlurryAgent.init(this, FLURRY_KEY); 
        }`

Comment: Do I need to add this flurry code in all the activities to be able to use flurry analytics?

Comment: That can be checked on the documentation @ flurry.com. Generally these go into application class since its global

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first error is due to the `@Override` annotation on top of your first `onCreate` method. `onCreate` is a method of your superclass, `Activity`, and is defined like your second `onCreate` method, it needs to be protected and take a `Bundle` object as argument, otherwise it doesn't override the superclass method.
To fix this, simply delete your first `onCreate` method and move the code you need to the second one.

The second error is due to the fact that you haven no variable with the name `XYB***********2P` so the compiler doesn't know what to do with that.

Since the [init method of FlurryAgent](http://flurrydev.github.io/FlurryAndroidSDK5xAPI/classcom_1_1flurry_1_1android_1_1FlurryAgent.html#af1f49f4f3601933c18be1b262d6a06b6) (see docs) takes a String, you could define one like so :

```
private final static String FLURRY_KEY = "XYB***********2P";
```

then use it like this :

```
FlurryAgent.init(this, FLURRY_KEY);
```

Comment: And make sure you import ll the right classes, it seems you're missing the import of Activity, at least.

Comment: Do I need to add this flurry code in all the activities to be able to use flurry analytics?

Comment: I'm no expert, but according to the docs, you can simply initialize it once in the Application class. Have a look at their [Getting Started page](https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/analytics/gettingstarted/android/), it should get you going.